# Portainer docker container behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: server, nginx, https, letsencrypt, reverse-proxy

I have set up an nginx reverse proxy on an Ubuntu 22.04 server and I have successfully obtained ssl certificate from lets encrypt. The two keys are stored here:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.ddns.net/fullchain.pem;
/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.ddns.net/privkey.pem
```

and in my default nginx config I have two paths `helloworld` and `portainer`. Both paths redirects to docker containers.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.ddns.net;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name test.ddns.net;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.ddns.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.ddns.net/privkey.pem;

    location /helloworld {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:32768;
    }

    location /portainer {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
```

The helloworld path works as expected and loads an html page with https protocol (so my ngnix config is correct). But portainer path not. I tried port 9000, port 8000, port 9443. Non of them worked. I get 404 error, or request sent via http while expected https, or other errors. Does anyone by chance has the same setup and is able to help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

###### Regarding the ports you mentioned trying:

- Port `8000` is used by Portainer Edge Agent to remotely manage and interact with edge devices and their services. Since you haven't mentioned anything about edge computing, this port is not necessary for your use case.
- Port `9000` was used to establish a connection to the Portainer web UI, but is now only available for legacy reasons and it is highly recommended to avoid using it.
- Portainer added support for `https` in mid-2021, making port `9443` the [recommended](https://www.portainer.io/blog/how-to-correctly-secure-portainer-when-presented-on-the-internet) option for secure connections to the Portainer web UI. Therefore, that's the one you should use.

###### Regarding your Nginx configuration:

You were close enough, but in order for Portainer to work on a subpath (like the one you want), you should add a **trailing slash** to both `location` and `proxy_pass` fields, as shown below:

```
location /portainer/ {
     proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/;
}
```

After you restart Nginx using the command `sudo systemctl restart nginx`, the 404 error should be resolved.

Comment: It was not my intention to imply any oversight on your part regarding the mention of port 9443 in the latter portion of your response. However, my response centers on the use of trailing slashes as a means of resolving the 404 error. Thus, I cannot concur that your statement is "exactly the same". Additionally, I did not assert that port 9000 is inoperable. Nonetheless, as I advised the inquirer to exclusively utilize port 9443, it was essential to provide a comprehensive explanation for the reasons behind the exclusion of the other ports.

Comment: You're right, and I'm sorry - I missed the part about the trailing slash. I've edited your post to highlight this important difference.  Actually, I'll remove my answer, since I believe yours are more correct, and mine was merely a qualified guess, which didn't work out. Thanks for pointing out - and upvoted!

Comment: You are welcome, no problem. Thanks for the upvote! 

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I've been really struggling with it for days.